# traceroute6 connect: Network is unreachable

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6

I'm experiencing this problem on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 21, running in Amazon EC2. I have full LAN and Internet connectivity, and I can successfully run

```
traceroute gmail.com
```

But running

```
traceroute6 gmail.com
```

produces:

> connect: Network is unreachable

Running

```
tracepath6 gmail.com
```

gets

> 1:  send failed

This may be unrelated, but running

```
tracepath gmail.com
```

gets out to my ISP before returning loads of "no reply" lines. I'm using an Engenius router with IPv6 enabled, but IPv6 pass-through disabled.
Any ideas?

ip -6 addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000 inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe0e:12ab/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: The `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route` info might be handy to know.

Comment: Update: I just got the same results using an Ubuntu instance on AWS - so it obviously has nothing to do with my router.

Comment: Here's ip -6 addr: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe0e:12ab/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: And here is ip -6 route:  fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256

Comment: Uh so only link-local and no route. That's not going to help v6 packets get off the client systems. Can the Engenius router advertise a route (SLAAC or dhcpdv6) or something?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it turns out that it's also a problem with my AWS instance - so it's not specific to the Engenius. - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need IPv6 connectivity from your ISP to be able to use IPv6. AWS is known to not support IPv6 on their instances. You have to make your ISP do the right thing and provide you with IPv6 or you have to get IPv6 using e.g. tunnelbroker.net

Comment: Switching to another provider with native IPv6 support sounds like a better option than a tunnel.

Comment: If one is available: certainly

Comment: Thanks. IPv6 is a whole new world for me...one I hope to avoid as much as possible for as long as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try tcptraceroute:

```
sudo apt install tcptraceroute
tcptraceroute gmail.com
```